# Как сделать запись в файл?

Tags: python

Как мне можно сделать запись в файл и потом считывание?

Допустим, в файле есть строка 1 "Password" . При запуске программа запрашивает пароль и при вводе того, что написано в файле настроек, то программа выполняет действия дальше. (Это я сделал уже), но мне еще нужно, чтобы после ввода (естественно правильного) у юзера спрашивалось о том какая ОСь у него. И после ответа, Допустим 1. Win XP 2. Win 7 и т.д. В файл записывалась вторая строчка, допустим, User OS = Win XP, Win 7 и т.д. И после ответа выполнялись определенные действия связаные с ОС. Допустим если значение User OS = Win XP то выполняется функция win_xp_init() . Которая выводит сообщение Hello user on the Windows xp. Извиняюсь забыл добавить на Python 2.7

Comment: Еще раз - экстрасенсы в отпуске!

Comment: На чём писать то? На мониторе?

Comment: ага, пальцем водить! :) на тачскрине.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем чудо телепатии...

Наверное в Вашем случае (модификация конфигурационного файла) самым правильным будет открыть на запись **file-2** (лучше сгенерить уникальное имя), скопировать в него нужные данные из исходного **file.conf**, а потом добавить новые.

После закрытия файлов переименовать их: file.conf в file.conf.bak, а file-2 в file.conf

Конкретные символы (набиваемые Вами в редакторе) зависят от используемого Вами языка программирования и ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант в лоб с использованием файла конфигурации:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

def windows():
    print "User has Windows"

def linux():
    print "User has Linux"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = SafeConfigParser()
    parser.read("test.conf")
    password_answer = raw_input("Enter password: ")
    if not password_answer == parser.get("test", "password"):
        print "Wrong password!"
        exit()
    os_answer = raw_input("Enter your OS: ").lower()
    if os_answer == "windows":
        windows()
    elif os_answer == "linux":
        linux()
    else:
        print "Your OS ain't supported"
    parser.set("test", "user_os", os_answer)
    parser.write(open("test.conf", "w"))
```

Это файл test.conf:

```
[test]
password = test
```