# Как записывать в файл на python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, функциональное-программирование

У меня скрипт создает беседы в ВКонтакте, мне нужно в отдельный файл записывать айди созданных бесед. Как это сделать?

Comment: если вы что-то не поняли задайте вопрос.. :)

Comment: взять id беседы и [записать в файл](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/)... какие сложности что не получается? ps удалите ответ (который токовым не является, это комментарий)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать запись в файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/71106/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос из базовых основ языка. Ответ есть в первых уроках практически любого курса по python.

```py
your_id = "Ваш Id полученный где-то в коде "
with open("myfile.txt", mode="w") as f:
    f.write(your_id)
```